# how to add score to higher or lower game

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from random import *

while True:

    random1 = randint(1,20)

    random2 = randint(1,20)

    print("h = higher, l = lower, s = same, q = quit")

    print(random1)

    a = input()

    if a.lower() == 'q':
            break

    print(random2)

    if a.lower() == 'h' and random1 < random2:

        print("Well done")

    elif a.lower() == 'l' and random1 > random2:

        print("Well done")

    elif a.lower() == 's' and random1 == random2:

        print("Well done")
    else:

        print("Loser")
```

So what I am trying to do is have x as my score. And when the answer prints "Well Done" I would like it to add 10 points to my score and then print the score. The thing is the score seems to reset loads of times throughout the game and I would like it to either add 10 to the score or stay the same. Does anyone know a way of doing this in my program. I can't imagine it would be too hard but I am only a beginner and still learning. At the moment I have no score at all added to my program, just so you can show me the easiest/ best way too approach this. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: You talk about the score but there is no attempt at implementing scoring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x = 0 # initialize the score to zero before the main loop
while True:

    ...

    elif a.lower() == 's' and random1 == random2:
        x += 10 # increment the score
        print("Well done. Your current score is {0} points".format(x))
```

anyway, the whole code could be shortened to:

```
from random import *
x = 0
while True:
    random1 = randint(1,20)
    random2 = randint(1,20)
    print("h = higher, l = lower, s = same, q = quit")
    print(random1)
    a = input().lower()
    if a == 'q':
        break

    print(random2)

    if ((a == 'h' and random1 < random2) or
        (a == 'l' and random1 > random2) or
        (a == 's' and random1 == random2)):
        x += 10
        print("Well done. Your current score is: {0}".format(x))
    else:
        print("Loser")
```

Comment: Thats perfect. I see the mistake I had made. I had "x = 0" within the main loop. Which caused it to reset every time. Now it is working perfectly. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

Simply add a variable:

```
score = 0 #Variable that keeps count of current score (outside of while loop)

while True:
...
    elif a.lower() == 'l' and random1 > random2:
        score += 10 #Add 10 to score
        print("Well done")
    else:
        #Do nothing with score as it stays the same
        print("Loser")
```

Comment: It isn't really clear in your answer that `score` needs to be initialized outside the while loop.